# How to call openURL method in today widgets when app is not running in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8-today-widget, openurl, today-extension

While implementing Today Widgets Open URL method is called while it is running in background or currently running in foreground .
  But when it is not lunched ,it don't call `openURL` but call `didFinishLunch`. So How to handle this situation .
 I am sharing the data in the form of group capabilities.How to handle it.

Comment: Use local notification, it will launch your app and then you can call `openURL` in `didFinishLunch`

Answer (score 1):

You Can Get the url in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions from launchOptions.

```
 if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey])
    {
        NSLog(@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey %@",[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey]);
    }
```